# How to open mobile view of website in Windows Phone application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am trying to open a web page in my Windows Phone application. But, I am unable to open desired web page in its mobile form.

I am adding web browser in my XAML:

```
</Grid>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="wb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="686" Width="480" Loaded="wb_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is my backend code in C#:

```
private void wb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://facebook.com/mobile", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

But I am unable to view the actual mobile web page of Facebook. This code makes Facebook to look very much ugly.

I tried with `http://m.facebook.com` also, but this is also not helping.

Please suggest me, how can I correct this error to have actual mobile web page of Facebook in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong mobile url, mobile sites are usually differentiated by the prefix m such as facebooks' actual mobile page `https://m.facebook.com` which is the subdomain usage for the mobile apps. The mobile page you linked to is to install a mobile app; which is a standard html viewing type page and not mobile.